# Get Facebook user access_token for FQL/Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token

I am currently trying to get a user access_token to submit an FQL query to the Facebook Graph API. The goal is ultimately to fetch the most recent statuses from a FB Page.

I have the app access_token by way of hitting the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&grant_type=client_credentials
```

When I write my FQL query `(SELECT status_id, message, time FROM status WHERE uid="[PAGE_ID]")` using the Graph API explorer tool, it works with no issue due to the  explorer using my User access_token by default. Debugging this access_token in the FB debugger tool verifies that it is using both my app_id and my user_id. When I use the app access_token to make the request (to `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=[QUERY ABOVE]&access_token=[APP_TOKEN]`) , I get the following error:

`{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":102}}`

Is there some method of accessing a user access_token using the FB API?

Thanks!!

Comment: To get a user access token, you have to have the user connect to your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your FQL query and you should be able to get what you want. Querying `status` requires a user access token, but querying the `stream` of a public page can be done with an app access token. The `type = 46` limits the results to status updates.

```
SELECT post_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = [PAGE_ID] 
  AND type = 46
```